# Add translations string automatically to JSON

Tags: node.js, reactjs, internationalization, i18next

My react app have lots of translations strings in it that need to be updated frequently into a JSON file. I'm looking for a way to automate the process so it won't be so tedious.

The best thing will be a small Node script that will run over all my JS files and every time I wrote something like `` t('example`) `` it will add it to a JSON file as key and value (`{"example":"example"`}).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`i18next-scanner`](https://github.com/i18next/i18next-scanner) does exactly what you've described.